# Is there a way to add a Markdown link within an HTML Table in an Azure DevOps wiki page?

Tags: html, azure-devops, markdown

I am creating an HTML table for an Azure DevOps wiki page (I need to use an HTML table as opposed to a Markdown table for proper color formatting).  Within this table, I need to create links to other wiki pages. The format for linking wiki pages in Markdown is the following:
`[text to display](/parent-page/child-page)`. However, I do not know of a way to do this using HTML tags without listing the URL: `<a href="absolute or relative URL">text to display</a>`. I would like to avoid linking the URL as I am creating the wiki page by using a script to generate a `.md` file containing all the links, and linking with the URL requires the use of a page ID number and other information as opposed to simply the name of the wiki page, making the process more difficult.

I have seen that you can nest markdown within your HTML in Azure DevOps, but you must include a blank line between the HTML element and the markdown. However, adding this blank line seems to mess up the format of all the subsequent rows in the table. Below is the format of my HTML table in the Azure DevOps wiki page.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Table Header</th><th>Table Header</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

[Other wiki page](/parent-page/child-page)
</td><td>Table cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Table cell 3</td><td>Table cell 4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Below is an example of the table I am trying to create based on the above HTML, by using an HTML table with Markdown links in Azure DevOps.

| Table Header | Table Header |
| --- | --- |
| [Other wiki page](/parent-page/child-page) | Table cell 2 |
| Table cell 3 | Table cell 4 |

In summary, is there a way that I can create an HTML link using the `/parent-page/child-page` format without the use of the URL? If not, is there a way to use a Markdown link within an HTML table in an Azure DevOps wiki page without messing up the table format?

Thanks